# d3.scale.log cannot read property log of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to replicate a map that I saw in a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jvoTV54nXw) 
 and I cannot seem to get it right even if the code on my editor is the same as his. When I tried to debug my code I get the following error

> Cannot read property log of undefined in the d3.scale.log.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var outerWidth=500;
var outerheight=250;
var margin={left:-50, top:0, right:-50, bottom:0};
var xColumn="longitude";
var yColumn="latitude";
var rColumn="population";
var peoplePerPixel=1000000;
var innerWidth=outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var innerHeight=outerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", outerWidth)
 .attr("height", outerheight);

var g= svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," +margin.top +")");
 var xScale= d3.scale.log()
  .range([0,innerWidth]);
 var yScale= d3.scale.log()
  .range([innerHeight,0]);
 var rScale= d3.scale.sqrt();
function render (data){
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){return d[xColumn]; }));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){return d[yColumn]; }));
rScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d){return d[xColumn]; })]);

var circles= svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
circles.enter().append("circle");
circles
 .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]);})
 .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]);})
 .attr("r", function(d){ return rScale(d[rColumn]);});
 circles.exit().remove();
  }
 function type(d) {
  d.latitude=+d.latitude;
  d.longitude=+d.longitude;
  d.population=+d.population;
  return d;
     }

 d3.csv("map_cities.csv",type, render)


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial uses D3 v3.5.5 whereas you are using D3 v4. Because the new version uses ES6 modules the namespaces of the previous versions had to be flattened. The changelog has the details for your case:

> ## [Scales (d3-scale)](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md)
>
> Pursuant to the great namespace flattening:
>
> *[…]*
>
> - d3.scale.sqrt ↦ [d3.scaleSqrt](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleSqrt)
> - d3.scale.log ↦ [d3.scaleLog](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLog)

Although not explicitly mentioned in your question, I have also included the adjustment for `d3.scale.sqrt` which would be the next problem you were to run into.